# How to move to the left ToggleButton in vertical LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

My activity screen is created as vertical LinearLayout. I want to add ToggleButton to the left side of the screen. I tried to make it with gravity parameter like here:

```
<ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="left"/>
```

However it put the text on the button to the left and not the button itself. How can I move the button to the left in vertical LinearLayout?

Comment: Do you want everything left-aligned ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that your LinearLayout is defines **android:layout_width="match_parent"**...use this:

```
 <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
```

**android:layout_gravity** == the alignment on the layout this element is included (i.e. the LinearLayout)

**android:gravity** == the alignment of the internal elements (i.e. the text inside the Button).